# Row,tooltip, one line text

Tags: android, text, dart, flutter, row

i want to make one line text with additional tooltip text then another text. I've tried like this. But this row overflowing screen size.

*Widget tree example*

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE4E4E4),
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
           child: new Stack(
             children: <Widget>[
               _getBackground(),
               _getGradient(),
               _getContent()
             ],
           ),
         ),
    
Widget _getContent() {
        return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 300, 15, 0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  overviewText,
                  style: style1,
                  maxLines: 1,    
                ),
                    Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Text("dsdsd4233333333333334dsad "),
                      TapTooltip(child:Text(" dsds"),message: "dsds342",),
                      Text(" dsasddddddddddddddsaaaaaaaaaaaasds"),
                       ]));}}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riLnF.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you wanna achieve? Acutally it's not so clear from your question. Could you provide a picture supporting it? When you say "overflowing" are you meaning you're getting an overflow error or that this row takes the entire screen?

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. I just need plain text with tooltip texts between. TextSpan will be great for my needs, but it not allow to put in Tooltip Widget.https://i.stack.imgur.com/riLnF.jpg

Comment: Hard to say if you didn't post the entire widget tree. It's possible to see the entire layout? Who's your Row's parent?

Comment: I edited my question, please look at widget tree.

Comment: I've already post my answer. I guess it could be okay with your widget tree (if you are okay to have ellipeses (`...`)). You can wrap your trailing `Text` widget in `Expanded` and set the `overlay`. Do not use " " (blank space) as prefix of the latter `Text` widget. Put it on the middle widget instead. Let me know.

Comment: But i need this text visible without ellipeses.It should goes on next line like normal text will do. Set Overlay? Where can i find it?

Comment: I said "overlay"... sorry, my mistake. I mean "overflow". If you wanna wrap the Text you need to use only one Tooltip and only one Text. Is mandatry for you to have the tooltip set on the midlle region of the text? Is an option to use only one tooltip and text? I've update my answer.

Comment: But i really need a lot of tooltip between normal texts. Its Will be  like descriptions of some difficult words.

Comment: Okay, now your needs are more clear. I suggest you to update your answer to better explain those needs to have tooltips for many words inside a long phrase that must wrap if it's too long.